# How to hide an empty view block when using a contextual filter and NO file fields?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to figure out how to hide a view block when it has no rows. Though [this questions is similar](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107412/hiding-a-view-if-empty-when-contextual-filter-is-already-used), it's not the same. In my situation I am also using a contextual filter but have no file fields so the answer in that question doesn't apply.

I've tried **global: null** as a second contextual filter but still the block shows with just the title.

Can anyone help me solve this issue.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  another filter it's not important which field , as example if you have `Content:title` ( or any field you have in fields row) and  set filter is it's not empty.

The mechanism is simple, contextual filter cause view not consider as empty even thought there is no any row, and when you add a filter on a field that not exists it cause view considered as empty. **So only add one of your view field to  filter and  check if it is not empty**

Comment: @dibs you 're welcome, follow me on twitter, sometimes I need a hug ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried various methods suggested in various places, including this one from @zhilevan, but the only way I could get it to work was to remove the title from the block and add it in as a header to the block.